# Get the IP address and port of Rstudio Server

Tags: r, rstudio, rstudio-server

I am looking for a way to get the IP address and port of Rstudio Server. I can see them in the web browser, but I want to use it to programe.

```
> RStudio.Version()
$citation

To cite RStudio in publications use:

  RStudio Team (2018). RStudio: Integrated Development for R. RStudio, Inc., Boston, MA URL http://www.rstudio.com/.

A BibTeX entry for LaTeX users is

  @Manual{,
    title = {RStudio: Integrated Development Environment for R},
    author = {{RStudio Team}},
    organization = {RStudio, Inc.},
    address = {Boston, MA},
    year = {2018},
    url = {http://www.rstudio.com/},
  }


$mode
[1] "server"

$version
[1] ‘1.2.1335’

> Sys.info()
                              sysname                               release                               version 
                              "Linux"          "3.10.0-957.12.2.el7.x86_64" "#1 SMP Tue May 14 21:24:32 UTC 2019" 
                             nodename                               machine                                 login 
              "localhost.localdomain"                              "x86_64"                             "unknown" 
                                 user                        effective_user 
                                "wsx"                                 "wsx"
```

Comment: Would you like to extract the IP/Port from the RStudio client's R console?

Comment: @JDG Yes. I tried using `system()` to find, but I don't know how to locate the information.